# Revert after merge --squash

Tags: git

I have a webapp where a new feature has been merged down to the develop branch and is ready to be merged to master and deployed from there. It's a rather complicated feature and I need to be able cleanly revert if anything behaves unexpectedly.

I'm planning this:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash develop
git commit -m 'Merged...etc'
```

All easy enough and straightforward. And if I do need to rollback, I'm hoping to be able to merely do this:

```
git checkout master
git revert HEAD
```

However if this is necessary, I will need to fix the issue in develop and re-merge at a later date. And I read this in git help revert:

> Reverting a merge commit declares that you will never want the tree changes brought in by the merge.
>   As a result, later merges will only bring in tree changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors
>   of the previously reverted merge

Which suggests I might not be able to re-merge the same code at a later date. Or does the use of --squash mean that this is not considered to be a merge commit (as the commit is a separate transaction) and I can re-merge in the future.

So I'm looking for some clarification on whether this is viewed as a merge commit by git, or 
not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linus Torvalds can explain it better than I](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).

TL;DR: To merge changes in after a reverted merge, you need to revert the revert (or maybe something different).

That said, in your case, you wont create a merge commit. A merge commit has 2 (or more) parents. `git merge --squash && git commit` will create a commit with one parent.

Comment: I was thinking that this wouldn't be a merge commit, but wanted some reassurance so thanks for that. Hopefully, it'll all go fine and I won't need to revert at all...